# Always timeout when running unit test on CircleCI for SailsJS controller

Tags: unit-testing, timeout, sails.js, geometry, circleci

My Sails Controler like this:

```
function sendUser(req ,res) {
  console.log('sendUser running');
  return res.send('jerryc');
}

module.exports = {
  user: sendUser
};
```

and my unit test like this:

```
var should = require('should');
var supertest = require('supertest');
var express = require('express');

describe('request', function () {

  it('try to request express app by use supertest', function (done) {
    var app = express();

    app.get('/user', function(req, res){
      res.send(200, { name: 'tobi' });
    });

    supertest(app)
      .get('/user')
      .end(function(err, res){
        if (err) return done(err);
        done();
      });
  });

  it('try to request sails app by use supertest', function (done) {
    var app = sails.hooks.http.app;

    supertest(app)
      .get('/user')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        if (err){
          return done(err);
        }
        console.log(res.text);
        done();
      });
  });

  it('try to request sails app by use supertest and timeout is over 200s', function (done) {
    this.timeout(200000);
    var app = sails.hooks.http.app;

    supertest(app)
      .get('/user')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        if (err){
          return done(err);
        }
        console.log(res.text);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

the result is :

1. on case one, i using express app and it response in time(<1500ms)
2. on case two, i using sails app and response timeout (>1500ms), but the code `console.log('sendUser running')` executed and output a message: 'sendUser running'
3. on case three, i using sails app angain, but this time `this.timeout = 200000`, and it response successfully, the response time over 120s!!!

so, my question is:
Any reasons will lead to slow response on circle with sails?
And solution to make response quicke than over 120s?
By the way,i running all these test case normally on my local environment machine.

Comment: Did you lift sails before test running?